# Autocompletar campos mediante un select

Tags: jquery, laravel

quiero autocompletar informacion mediante un select como se muestra en la siguiente
imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy extrayendo informacion de otra tabla llamada medicamentos la cual tiene la siguiente
estructura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo uso del model receta, para guardar la informacion correspondiente a su tabla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md">
    <label for="apellido"><b>Medicamento1</b></label>

    <select name="medicamento1[]" id="medicamento" class="form-control medicamento" onchange="cambiarData()">
        @foreach ($medicamentos as $medicamento)
        <option value="{{ $medicamento->id }}">{{ $medicamento->nombre }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <label for=""><b>Descripcion</b></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="descripcion1" />

    <label for=""><b>Tiempo de uso</b></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="tiempo_uso1" />
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-12 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <label for="floatingTextarea" class="form-label"><b>Historia clinica</b></label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="hist_clinica" placeholder="Historia clinica" id="motivo"
            style="height: 150px" style="resize: none"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-12 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <label for="floatingTextarea" class="form-label"><b>Diagnostico a investigar</b></label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="diagnostico" placeholder="Diagnostico a investigar" id="motivo"
            style="height: 150px" style="resize: none"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 <script>
    $("#medicamento").select2({
        theme: "bootstrap4"
    })


    $('.medicamento1').on('change', function() {

    var tiempo_uso = $("option:selected", this).data('tiempo_uso');
    $('#tiempo_uso').val(tiempo_uso);

    console.log(tiempo_uso);

    var descripcion = $("option:selected", this).data('descripcion');
    $('#descripcion').val(descripcion);

    console.log(descripcion);


    });

    })

</script>
```

No he podido dar con la solucion, si me pueden proveer un ejemplo seria de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Te recomiendo por favor expliques mejor tu duda, ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: @BetaM, no se avanzar mas de ahi, me puedes proveer un ejemplo funcional.?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas agregar los valores con `data` asi:

```
<option value="{{ $medicamento->id }}" data-descripcion="{{ $medicamento->descripcion }}" data-tiempo="{{ $medicamento->tiempo_uso}}">{{ $medicamento->nombre }}</option>
```